# Web scraping of a betting site with selenium. Incomplete event list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a program to get some odds from the "Eurobet.it" site using selenium to open the page containing the "ChanceMix". It seems that it works, but when the games take place in more than one date the list I get is incomplete. It contains only those of the first/second date, but not the next ones. I tried various solutions but without results. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


link = 'https://www.eurobet.it/it/scommesse/#!/calcio/eu-champions-league/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)

# Find the "ChanceMix" button by xpath and store it as a webdriver object
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'ChanceMix')]")

# Click on the "ChanceMix" button to open the relevant page
element.click()

# Find the list of games
Games = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.box-sport")))

# Print the list of games
for x in range(0,len(Games)): print(Games[x].text)
```

Comment: What  is your expected output?

Comment: A list showing ALL the matches and the sports odds of the competition (in this case "UEFA Champions League"). Now, if you try to execute the code, you will have a list that shows only the first three matches of the competition. And the next ones? For some reason they are not there. I think the problem is in the "CSS Selector", probably not the right one.